# Need help creating permuation system of amino acids using java

Tags: java, permutation

My problem requires me to create a list of all 20 amino acids permutations based on a user imputed chain length. For example, I currently have code that works if the user wants a 3 chain length. This is 20^3 possibilities. So I have 3 nested for loops that run through all possibilities, then a counter that outputs the number of permutations to make sure the answer is correct. How could I code this method so it output permutations based on user input?

```
protected void getPermutations(int chainlength) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
                System.out.println(AcidArray[i].getTcode() + "-"
                        + AcidArray[j].getTcode() + "-"
                        + AcidArray[k].getTcode());
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("chain length = " + chainlength);
    System.out.println(counter + " permutations");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to receive input from a user?

Comment: No, this code only works to output permutations of 3 acids. I need this method to take the number of acids and input(which I can do), then output all permutations. If you follow this code, it only works for 3 acids, I just added the chainlength variable as a placeholder.

Comment: I need a new algorithm that will work for any number of chainlength inputted.

Comment: [Recursion](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html)

Answer (score 4):

[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is your friend in this situation

```
protected String getPermutations(int chainlength) {
    int counter = 0;
    if(chainlength > 0) { // so that the counter is not 1
        counter = getSubPermutations("", chainlength));
    }
    System.out.println("chain length = " + chainlength);
    System.out.println(counter + " permutations");
}

private int getSubPermutations(String prefix, int chainlength){
   if(chainlength == 0){ //The bottom of the stack, print out the combination
      System.out.println(prefix.substring(0,prefix.length-1)); //remove the final '-'
      return 1;
   } else {
      int counter = 0
      for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        //Add this level T code to the string and pass it on
        counter += getSubPermutations(prefix + AcidArray[i].getTcode() + "-", chainlength-1);
      }
      return counter;
   }
}
```

What this will do is make a tree of calls. If chainlength is one then it will call `getSubPermutations` with `1`. This will run through the for loop calling `getSubPermutations` again with the String for the first value and a chainlength of `0`. In this case the string will only have one T code in it. Each inner call will hit the first if statement so it will **print out the string containing one T code** and return `1`. All these will be added up so the counter returned to `getPermutations` will be 20. By this stage all the permutations will have been printed out.

As chain length increases `getSubPermuations` is called recursively. With a chainlength of `2` it will call `getSubPermutations` 20 times with a chain length of `1`, passing in the string of the T code. Each of these will call `getSubPermutations` with a chainlength of 0, **with a string containing two T codes**. This will then print out the full string and return `1`. These return values will get added up to 20 as in the previous example but now when they are returned to the next level they are added up to return a final 400 to `getPermutations` and 400 Strings will have been printed.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. But the point of the program is to actually output each permutation. So for my code it will output 8000 lines (seems excessive, but necessary). The counter was just to keep track

Comment: Calling the array.Tcode() outputs the name of the acid in a three leterr abrreviation

Comment: The `chainlength == 0` case will do the printing. It should give the same output as your current program with a chainlength of 3

Comment: @user2133337 I updated the explanation to show where the output happens

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved you can let everyone know by accepting the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work